# If php string is in geojson array

Tags: javascript, php, json, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to make a selection of country names via php, then do a check against my geojson to see if the country name I got from php matches any names in my json and if so, read the coordinates of it.

So basically I have ALL the countries in the geojson but only those that are found to match with my php variable get drawn with polygons.
[The example is using leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html), what if those countries where coloured only if my php variables with the country names matches?

I have a php string which i get like this:

```
$myCountry = get_field("country");
echo $myCountry;
```

> String name result is **Australia**

This is the var_dump of get_field()

```
 array(3) {
  ["country_name"]=>
  string(9) "Australia"
  ["city_name"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["state_name"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I have a geojson like this

```
 "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "sovereignt": "Australia"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    [-77.53466, 23.75975],
                    [-77.78, 23.71],
                    [-78.03405, 24.28615],
                    [-78.40848, 24.57564],
                    [-78.19087, 25.2103],
                    [-77.89, 25.17],
                    [-77.54, 24.34],
                    [-77.53466, 23.75975]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    [-77.82, 26.58],
                    [-78.91, 26.42],
                    [-78.98, 26.79],
                    [-78.51, 26.87],
                    [-77.85, 26.84],
                    [-77.82, 26.58]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    [-77, 26.59],
                    [-77.17255, 25.87918],
                    [-77.35641, 26.00735],
                    [-77.34, 26.53],
                    [-77.78802, 26.92516],
                    [-77.79, 27.04],
                    [-77, 26.59]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: Looks like data for your JavaScript AJAX, yes?

Comment: yes the geojson is an external js file but i am not using ajax, i am reading it with leaflet js

Comment: so, you need check if data in array from your php code or javascript?

Comment: i need to check if the variable i get from the php as per the question matches a value in the json. The php doesn't give me an array but variable

Comment: @PHPglue updated the question with the var_dump of get_field()

Comment: Make an AJAX request with JavaScript to a PHP page where you `echo json_encode(get_field('country'));`, then you can use the data on the Client Side, once it comes back to your AJAX success method. You may have to nest your AJAX within an Asynchronous Leaflet function, depending on what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: @PHPglue the json has coordinates for polygons. So i need to check my php country name against all the "sovereignt":  in the json and if it finds a match then load the whole bit  from "type": "Feature", till the end of the array block so that i can draw the polygon on the map

Comment: Test the result of my last comment against `geoJSONObj.properties.sovereignt`.